# How does C compiler store a macro variable?

Tags: c, macros

if I define a macro like below:

```
#define TEST_VARIABLE 10
```

How does the compiler store it internally? as an signed/unsigned integer?

I have a loop in my program:

```
for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < TEST_VARIABLE; loop++)
```

I want to check if extra instruction is added by compiler to type cast "loop" variable while comparing with TEST_VARIABLE. if TEST_VARIABLE is stored in different data type, extra instruction shall be required.

Comment: It doesn't store it. It's effectively a simple copy 'n' paste, so the compiler transforms your for-loop into `for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)`. FYI, the type of the literal `10` will be `int`.

Comment: The compiler proper has no knowledge of the preprocessor. It is run before compilation takes place. It just sees `10` which is a signed integer value. If you have your warnings cranked up high enough you should see a warning about comparing a signed to unsigned value. You could restate your literal value as `10U` to make it unsigned.

Comment: a macro is not a variable, and the compiler never sees it

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: "The compiler never sees it"? The macro? It very well sees the macro. (note the preprocessor is integrated into the compiler in most modern compilers). The standard does not require cpp and cc to be seperate programs. gcc for instance provides macros with the name of the current function. Would be not possible without this integration.

Comment: Whatever you try, it is an XY problem. Why do you care about instructions at all? If that is some embedded project: if you need a specific instruction sequence, use assembly code! But best is to avoid it. Relying on instruction timing is almost always a bad design approach and the road to (debugging, maintenance) hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the preprocessor performs macro replacement, it treats it as text. The fact that the replacement looks like a number is totally irrelevant during macro processing. When the compiler processes the result, it's exactly as if you'd typed the replacement in its place. So

```
for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < TEST_VARIABLE; loop++)
```

is treated identically to

```
for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
```

The compiler will interpret `10` as a `signed int`.

Comment: s/text/a stream of tokens/, at least for a conformant preprocessor. (I know, it's pedantry, but consider `loop < TEST_VARIABLE.0`)

Answer (score 1):

Macros created by `#define` are basically text substitution, and are handled by the preprocesser.  The result of the preprocessor is then handed to the compiler.

So when the preprocessor finishes with your code, the result is:

```
for (unsigned int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
```

*Then* the compiler reads and compiles this code.  So in this particular case, you have a numeric constant.  The type of this constant is `int`, since there is no type suffix or cast.